# How to fix Google Chrome loading the page twice when Response.ContentType is 'audio/wav'?

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-chrome

I have a very basic ASP.NET application which writes data downloads from a URL and passes it to the client as an **inline** audio(.wav) file. This works fine in IE, but in Chrome the Page_Load method is fired twice causing some other issues in the application.

The application works fine in Google Chrome (Page_Load method is only called once) if I pass on the file as an attachment. But when I specify the 'ContentType' as 'audio/wav' as an inline attachment (content-disposition = inline), the event is fired twice.

Interestingly, when I try remove the 'audio/wav' ContentType property but keep the file as an inline attachment, the page works fine and only loads once, displays the content as text on the page. So I am pretty sure the issue has something to do with the MIME type.

Here is the code I am using:

```
Response.ContentType = "audio/wav";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "inline;");
Response.BinaryWrite(httpClient.GetByteArrayAsync("url").Result);
Response.End();
```

This code works fine in IE but fires the page twice in Google Chrome. Please suggest a solution. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It seems when I added this header, it won't run twice. But that is really not what I wanted to do.

Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=ABC.pdf");